# Updating Cloned object issue Realm.io

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

i have cloned a RealmObject with primary key and it has been created fine, but when i update
a children from the cloned object, the original children is also updated, how can i update only cloned object?

```
Model *originalModel =[[Model allObjects] firstObject]; //original model

Model *cloneModel = [[Model alloc] initWithValue:originalModel]; //clone model

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];


[realm beginWriteTransaction];
cloneActivity.uuid =  @"new uuid";

for (ScreenModel *page in cloneActivity.screens) {
 //this line is also updating the original object
page.execution_uuid = @"new uuid";

}
[ActivityTreeModel createInRealm:realm withValue:cloneModel];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

when i do a simple update all the "originalModel" childrens are also updated

Comment: FYI: This was also filed as an issue on Realm's GitHub repo: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the identical issue filed in [Realm's GitHub repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2190):

Realm doesn't yet support creating standalone copies of linked objects when using `initWithValue:`

We are currently working on this feature, with the progress occurring on this pull request: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2043

In the mean time, you will have to manually perform the copying to create duplicates of the linked objects.

Also, as a head's up cross-posting of issues is not necessary. We track both SO and GitHub issues. Posting only to one place makes it easier for us to answer quickly!